# Accessing memory out of string bounds while printing

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Here's my ASM code:

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

boot:
    mov bx, string
    call print_string

    hlt

string:
    db 'Booting OS', 0

printloop:
    ; Move the character into al so the BIOS interrupt prints it
    mov al, [bx]
    int 0x10
    ; Increment bx by 1 so it goes to the next character of the string
    add bx, 1
    
    ; Check if the value is 0, if so, exit out of the loop, if it's not 0, continue looping
    mov cx, [bx]
    cmp cx, 0x0000
    jne printloop
    jmp print_fin

print_string:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x0e
    jmp printloop
    print_fin:
    popa
    ret


; Mark the device as bootable
times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; Add any additional zeroes to make 510 bytes in total
dw 0xAA55 ; Write the final 2 bytes as the magic number 0x55aa
```

Here's the output of the code:

Booting OS ŠÍƒÃ‹ƒù uòë`ëíaÃß

I'm fairly sure that's not what I entered.

I have no idea why it's going past the terminator..

Edit: I just tried setting the byte at the end of the string to `0x0000`, incase that's somehow different from `0`, it still went right past the terminator.

Comment: `mov cx, [bx]` loads a 16-bit word, i.e. two bytes.  Did you mean `mov cl, [bx]` and then apply your test to `cl`?  Or better, think about how you can design your loop to only load each byte once; at present you load every byte twice (except the first one).

Comment: Also `hlt` will only halt until an interrupt arrives, and then continue, at which point it will execute your string.  If you really want to hang the system, put your `hlt` in an infinite loop.  You can also `cli` first, but in principle a non-maskable interrupt could arrive.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ohhh. Yes, I did. I'm fairly sure that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: That would do it, because the byte after your null terminator is the opcode of `mov al, [bx]` which is certainly not zero.  So you will not end up with 16-bit zero in `cx`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those errors that would have gone by unnoticed if you had written the string right above the `TIMES` directive (and thus below the rest of the code). The first padding zero would have made it OK.

```
...
string:
    db 'Booting OS', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

---

> Edit: I just tried setting the **byte** at the end of the string to `0x0000`, incase that's somehow different from 0, it still went right past the terminator.

Your edit *could have solved the problem* were there no misconception about what `0x0000` means. The way you write your numerical constant does not impose any size information on the `DB` directive.

```
db 'Booting OS', 0
db 'Booting OS', 0x00
db 'Booting OS', 0x0000
db 'Booting OS', 0x00000000
```

All the above encode the same, appending a single zero **byte** to the text.

Your effort to solve it using 0x0000 would have worked via the `DW` directive, appending a single zero **word** to the text:

```
db 'Booting OS'
dw 0x0000
```

But even here, you could have written the terminator in many ways:

```
dw 0
dw 0x00
dw 0x0000
dw 0x00000000
```

---

Unrelated to the bounds issue, but the *print_string* code is way too complicated. Better use code like this:

```
  mov  si, string
  call print_string  ; -> SI (AX)

...

; IN (si) OUT (si) MOD (ax)
print_string:
  push bx
  mov  bx, 0x00007   ; BH is DisplayPage, BL is GraphicsColor
  jmp  .begin
.loop:
  mov  ah, 0x0E      ; BIOS.Teletype
  int  0x10
.begin:
  mov  al, [si]      ; \ Alternatively, you can use LODSB here
  inc  si            ; /
  cmp  al, 0
  jne  .loop
  pop  bx
  ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Does the complexity of a function in this kind of low-level environment really matter, when everything is on the scale of milliseconds?

Comment: @NickKnack My point about being too complicated was, that you needlessly jumped out of the *print_string* routine, only to jump back in, upon exiting the *printloop*. Inlining is definitely better. In todays assembly programming everything is on the scale of fractions of microseconds, but that does not mean we should write code that wastes execution time or storage bytes (or anything else). e.g. Your program is a bootsector program that is always going to be limited to just 512 bytes. Writing correct code with the least number of bytes would normally be desirable...

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it, the problem was that I was using a 16 bit register to compare an 8 bit one (`cx` instead of `cl`), and the `cmp` was comparing the wrong values.  (If I've gotten this wrong, please tell me what I got wrong. I've only just started learning ASM)